# How do I get an OOP Javascript Remember Button Selected Previously?

Tags: javascript, oop, adobe-illustrator

Please see the code below.  I'd like to have it so the javascript remembers the selected button from the last time the scrip was run.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var choice;
var w = new Window("dialog");
w.text = "Please Select Your Gemini Save Location Below";
var g = w.add("group");
var a = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "MN");
var b = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "WA");
var c = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "CA");
var d = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "TX");
var e = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "Remote");
var button = w.add("button", undefined, "OK");
var radiobuttons = [a, b, c, d, e];
a.checkedState = true;
for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        radiobuttons[i].onClick = function () {
            choice = radiobuttons[i].text;
        };
    })(I);
}
```

w.show();

Comment: What's wrong with the code provided? There doesn't seem to be any code in the snippet that would persist the state of the radio button and modify the output to default to the stored value. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm used to save prefs in a json file and read them from the file at the start of a script.

For you case it would be something like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// try to loads saved prefs or set default prefs
var prefs = load_prefs()
|| {a: true, b:false, c:false, d:false, e:false, choice:'MN'} 

var choice = prefs.choice; // <-- get choice from prefs;
var w = new Window("dialog");
w.text = "Please Select Your Gemini Save Location Below";
var g = w.add("group");
var a = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "MN");
var b = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "WA");
var c = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "CA");
var d = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "TX");
var e = g.add("radiobutton", undefined, "Remote");
var button = w.add("button", undefined, "OK");

// set the radiobutton from the prefs
a.value = prefs.a;
b.value = prefs.b;
c.value = prefs.c;
d.value = prefs.d;
e.value = prefs.e;

var radiobuttons = [a, b, c, d, e];
for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        radiobuttons[i].onClick = function () {
            choice = radiobuttons[i].text;
        };
    })(i);
}

w.show();

alert(choice);

// set the prefs from radiobuttons
prefs.a = a.value;
prefs.b = b.value;
prefs.c = c.value;
prefs.d = d.value;
prefs.e = e.value;
prefs.choice = choice; // <-- save choice

save_prefs(prefs); // save the prefs


// functions to load and save prefs

function load_prefs() {
    var file = File(Folder.temp + '/prefs.json')
    return (file.exists) ? $.evalFile(file) : false;
}

function save_prefs(prefs) {
    var file = File(Folder.temp + '/prefs.json')
    file.open('w');
    file.encoding = 'UTF-8';
    file.write(prefs.toSource());
    file.close();
}
```

Just in case. Of course you can use a loop to set radiobuttons from prefs and vice versa if you like. Something like this:

```js
// prefs
var prefs = {a:true, b:false, c:false, d:false, e:false};

// radiobuttons
var a = {}, b = {}, c = {}, d = {}, e = {};

// set radiobuttons from prefs
var radiobuttons = {a,b,c,d,e};
for (var btn in radiobuttons) radiobuttons[btn].value = prefs[btn];

console.log(radiobuttons)

// change values of some radiobuttons
a.value = false;
b.value = true;

// set prefs from radiobuttons
for (var pr in prefs) prefs[pr] = radiobuttons[pr].value;

console.log(prefs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Yuri, I've been testing this throughout today and found that even though the radio button still appears selected, my script does not work unless I still click on the button.

Comment: I've added the two lines in the script to read and to save the variable `choice`.

Comment: So, does it work after the update?

Comment: Yuri Khristich That seems to have done the trick!!   Thank you again for the Assist!